# The data is not showing in fields when i update data in updateview

Tags: python, django, django-forms

The data is not showing in fields when i update data in updateview

```
def dis_update(request, pk, template_name='sales/distributor_form.html'): 
    alldistributor = get_object_or_404(Distributor, pk=pk) 
    if request.method=='POST': 
        form = DistributorForm(request.POST, instance=alldistributor) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save() 
            return redirect('index.html') 
        else: 
            form=DistributorForm() 
            return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def dis_update(request, pk, template_name='sales/distributor_form.html'): 
    alldistributor = get_object_or_404(Distributor, pk=pk) 
    if request.method=='POST': 
        form = DistributorForm(request.POST, instance=alldistributor) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save() 
            return redirect('index.html') 
        else: 
            form=DistributorForm(instance=alldistributor) 
            return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
    else:
        form = DistributorForm(instance=alldistributor)
        return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: This is wrong; you shouldn't recreate the form in the first else, as it will hide any errors.

Comment: previous one was working, after editing its not working now

Comment: have reverted the ans @rabia, some people thinks having lot of reputation means they know everything